# Wi-Fi using only 0.01% of what it can, and a laggy browser and skype calls. Only on my computer

Tags: wireless-networking

My WiFi one day suddenly stopped working as it normally has before and apparently my WiFi is only using 0.01% of everything it can at a time and my browser is taking a very long time to load videos and websites. Also this only happens on my computer, everything else in the house or everything connected to the Wi-Fi works perfectly. 
Picture is in Norwegian sadly but this is what is happening:

[image: Picture is in Norwegian sadly but this is whats happening]

I do not know much about how WiFi and stuff like that works, so if you have any idea on how to fix this and you don't have enough explanation here, go ahead and ask me for more info.

Comment: Can you clarify what is happening, is your browsing slow? Your network connection normally only uses on as much as it needs so utilization of under 1% is fine for standard browsing.

Comment: If you can move the system around without too much trouble (laptop, say), try placing it *immediately adjacent* to the WiFi access point and see if the problems go away. Then update your question accordingly.

Comment: My Browser is normally taking an unusual amount of time to load in websites and videos, aswell as only online games lagging from time to time. And also i cannot move my computer but it is about 5-7 meters away from the Wi-Fi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem, and sadly it was my last resort. I rebooted my whole computer and it fixed itself.

Answer (score 2):

A network interface will normally use only a small percentage of the available network bandwidth at any given time. If you want to see the maximum bandwidth you can achieve on the interface then you need to run a test that will attempt to use all of the available bandwidth.  A common network tool for doing so is [Iperf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iperf), which is available for many different operating systems. If you install the software on a system and run it in "client" mode, you will need to test it with the same software running on another system where it runs in "server" mode.

There are test servers on the Internet you can test with; search for "public Iperf server" to find those. But keep in mind that the figure you will see is not necessarily the maximum achievable bandwidth for your Wi-fi connection, merely the maximum achievable bandwidth on the slowest part of the network path, which could be at the server end, somewhere within your Internet Service Provider's network, or somewhere else along the network path between your system and the destination system. A better test would be to install the software on two systems that share your Wi-fi network.

Alternatively, you can test with websites out on the Internet that provide speed testing capabilities. But again, the number you will see for the maximum bandwidth is limited by the slowest part of the network path, e.g. [Speedtest](http://www.speedtest.net) or [other bandwidth testing sites](http://support.moonpoint.com/network/Internet/ISP/usb720bwtesting/usb720-bw-tests.php).  You should see your Wi-Fi utilization go up when you run such tests, but it won't necessarily be 100%, if your Wi-fi connection speed is faster than some other part of the network path, which is likely, which is why a test like an iperf test between two systems connected to your Wi-Fi router will give you a better idea of what the maximum bandwidth is you can achieve for a system connected to your Wi-Fi router.

If you are just looking at your network utilization at an instant in time when not much may be happening over that network connection a usage of 0.01% isn't indicating a network problem, only telling you that there isn't much network activity on that interface at the instant you checked the utilization.

Comment: Well i have now done everything you said and sadly it didnt work, and also i just updated the question a bit, and it now says that i only have this problem on my specific pc. Sometimes my Wi-Fi will work perfectly for a small amount of minutes. But normally when i try to play a game or talk to friends, either the game lags (alot) or my friends cant hear me at all.

Comment: Have you checked the CPU utilization at the times you have problems to see if there is any abnormally high CPU utilization at the times the problem occurs? If it is a Microsoft Windows system, you can hit Ctrl-Alt-Del and choose "Task Manager" to view the CPU and memory utilization. It may be a network problem that is unrelated to CPU or memory loading, but I'd check those as well, since those can also cause problems with a system's responsiveness.

Comment: I have checked that yes and my CPU should be working perfectly fine, and i havent seen anything operating badly.